# XAMPP, PHP: echo adds two spaces to blob read from database

Tags: php, mysql, blob, mime

I read blob (word 2010 document) from mysql database and store it in $data variable. When I simply store that data directly in PHP like so:

```
file_put_contents('c:\\temp\\dump.docx', $data);
```

I can open dump.docx in Word (size matches original file). If I attempt to send $data like this:

```
ob_start();
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=' . $name);
header('Content-type: ' . $type);
ob_clean();
echo $data;
ob_end_flush();
exit;
```

The stored file is two bytes longer. There are two spaces in front:

[image: Downloaded word doc viewed in hex editor with two extra spaces in front]

To check if I somehow do not output those spaces, I called ob_get_contents() just before echo and dumped content to a file. File has zero bytes.
So it looks like echo is producing those two bytes.

Comment: Can you show all the code in the second bit, what file are you opening in the hex viewer, the temp one or the downloaded one. Also remove all the `ob_*` stuff, its not needed and could be hiding the underlying issue.

Comment: There could be two spaces before `<?php` in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the sugestions. As explained in my own answer it was due to ob_start call somewere earlier (it's not my code so I was not aware of that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's post that helped me:
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/163628/extra-space-at-beginning-of-downloaded-image/163644

ob_start was already called ealier. I needed to call only ob_clean() before sending content.

Comment: It's funny that I seem to follow the same pattern over and over, I can't find solution until I ask question here. Then answer somehow appears within 5 minutes from the post :)